# How to get child xml from an xml in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

My XML format is this :

```
<Main>
  <IsD>false</IsD>
  <IsN>true</IsN>
  <ID>826e03b3-191c-40c9-8a3d-f6607842fa5f</ID>
  <ClientId>c6a32c38-0398-4806-b82f-e924f96217fa</ClientId>
  <General>
    <IsD>false</IsD>
    <IsN>true</IsN>
    <State>New</State>
    <TypeID>1</TypeID>
    <ProductID>-1</ProductID>
    <PeriodId>1</PeriodId>
    <StateID>5</StateID>
    <Rating>8</Rating>
  </General>
  <Feature>
    <TypeID>2</TypeID>
    <DurationID>-1</DurationID>
    <ClassID>-1</ClassID>
    <Fee>2500</Fee>
    <BonusID>-1</BonusID>
    <BenefitID>15</BenefitID>
  </Feature>
</Main>
```

I have passes this xml to an stored procedure and in this stored procedure I am saving all `Main` child node data in main table.

But now for the general and feature table i am using another sp and i want to pass all child nodes on  tag to this generalinertionsp as xml and same as feature.

but how can i passed these nodes to another sp.

How can i read inner child node vales as an xml and pass a partial xml to an another sp???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@x` is your XML variable

```
 select @x.query('/Main/General')
 select @x.query('/Main/Feature')
```

will give your child nodes

Answer (score 2):

You can select fragments of your original XML by using the `.query()` function in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '... (your XML here).....' 

SELECT 
    GeneralNode = @input.query('Main/General'),
    FeatureNode = @input.query('Main/Feature')
```

You can now pass this XML fragment into your other stored procedure to be processed there.